# Seleccion de botón con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

En mi formulario HTML quiero recoger el `value` de botón y que además active el método `next click` . El problema es que hace la acción `next click` pero no selecciona el botón, por tanto no recojo el `value`.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="botonnombre" value="botonvalor" class="next action-button">
```

JavaScript

```
$(".next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var current_fs = $(this).parent(); // Recuperamos el fieldset parent que contiene el botón "next"
    var next_fs = $(this).parent().next(); // Recuperamos el HTML siguiente
    var previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev(); // Recuperamos el HTML anterior
    //Si ha rellenado todos los campos//
    var isValid = validateFieldset(current_fs);

    if (isValid) {
        // Busca el paginador y cuando coincide el índice con el <li> del elemento "progressbar", le añade la clase "active"
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        // Si el fieldset anterior NO es el progressbar, entonces lo ocultamos
        if (previous_fs.attr('id') !== 'progressbar') {
            // Ocultamos el fieldset anterior
            previous_fs.hide();
        }
```

Comment: Ahí falta código... te has quedado corto copiando o está así en tu archivo? Cuando preguntes algo te recomiendo que nos des un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu error para poder ayudarte correctamente. Especialmente cuando se trata de cosas de web, ya que para eso tenemos la posibilidad de añadir fragmentos html/css/javascript en StackOverflow usando el icono que parece una hoja de papel con los símbolos `<>`.